# How do I create a filter in Power Apps that disables other filters

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to create 3 filters in Power Apps that I want to work uniquely (when one is selected the other 2 are automatically set to false)

I have created 3 buttons with the following code -

```
Button 1 - UpdateContext({FilterbyAA:!FilterbyAA})
Button 2 - UpdateContext({FilterbyBB:!FilterbyBB})
Button 3 - UpdateContext({FilterbyCC:!FilterbyCC})
```

My Gallery then has the code

```
If(
  FilterbyAA=true;
  Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="AA"); 
  If(
    FilterbyBB=true;
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="BB");
    If(
      FilterbyCC=true;
      Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="CC");
      Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off")
    )
  )
)
```

I am trying to change it to set the other filters to false when one is selected but the following code doesn't work. Can someone please assist with the correct syntax.

```
If(
  FilterbyAA=true;
  Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="AA") AND FilterbyBB=false AND FilterbyCC=false; 
  If(
    FilterbyBB=true;
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="BB") AND FilterbyAA=false AND FilterbyCC=false;
    If(
      FilterbyCC=true;
      Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="CC") AND FilterbyBB=false AND FilterbyAA=false;
      Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off")
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the logic in your buttons to set the other filters to false:

```
Button 1 - UpdateContext({FilterbyAA:!FilterbyAA; FilterbyBB:false; FilterbyCC:false})
Button 2 - UpdateContext({FilterbyBB:!FilterbyBB; FilterbyAA:false; FilterbyCC:false})
Button 3 - UpdateContext({FilterbyCC:!FilterbyCC; FilterbyAA:false; FilterbyBB:false})
```

At that point you can use your original logic. Notice that you can use multiple conditions in a single If call, which can make it a little easier to understand:

```
If(
  FilterbyAA=true;
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="AA"); 
  FilterbyBB=true;
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="BB");
  FilterbyCC=true;
    Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off";PILLAR.Value="CC");
  Filter(EVENTDETAILS;TYPE="Once Off")
)
```